# Помогите найти ошибку Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Tags: pdo

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER By id DESC LIMIT $start, $num ";
$qery = $pdo->query($qry);
echo "<h2> Новини </h2>";
do
{
  echo $qery['zagolovok'], $qery['news_text'];
}
while ($qery = $qery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы предопределяете переменную `$qery` (кстати скорее всего вы хотели написать `$query`)

```
while ($qery = $qery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

А поскольку вы используете do{}while() то первая итерация проходит норм, а на второй у вас в переменной уже массив значений + еще будет ошибка, если запрос в БД вернет пустой результат, то у вас цикл 1 раз выполнится, а результатов там ведь не будет.

Так что правильнее писать так:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER By id DESC LIMIT $start, $num ";
$query = $pdo->query($sql);
echo "<h2> Новини </h2>";
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['zagolovok'], $row['news_text'];
}
```

И еще лучше переменный в запрос не ставить, а использовать [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Answer (score 1):

while ($qery = $qery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); ошибка тут

один цикл проходит, потом $qery превращается в массив.

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER By id DESC LIMIT $start, $num ";
$qery = $pdo->query($qry);
echo "<h2> Новини </h2>";
while ($row = $qery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['zagolovok'], $row['news_text'];
}
```

должно быть как-то так.